# converting string to number in order to to compare them faster

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11

I have set of strings (it may be more than 10000 item). This set of data is going to be an input for some optimization algorithm which means that many many comparison operation will happen on them. The only comparison operation is to be equal or not.

The Question:
From performance point of view: Is it a good idea to convert these strings into numbers (by a method or another) and then run the Algorithm on this numbers?

P.S. the time it will take till all strings become numbers is not a problem cause i will do it and store it in the database again so it's one time thing.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea, you could simply replace them with the index in an array where they are stored and remove duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing input data many many times"? To test if some string is in the set of strings? Use precomputed hashes. But simply comparing constant strings to each other many-many times has no sense.

Comment: If there are *many* comparisons, then convert from text to internal format.  Compare many times using the internal format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of the usage of your data. I cannot tell the answer before you give us more detail. But I want ask you some questions:

1) Will you sort those items? std::set is your friend because the insertion time is O(log N)

2) How you will store the result? In string format or int format (i.e. Database field is string or int)

It may be a concern, but I think the conversion is not a big and heavy overhead

3) How large is the variable, is char (0-255), int, long, double?

if char, int, long, I recommend you to do so.
But not double, double == double is a bad idea.

4) all data are some type? any exception?

---

**Personally I suggest** to do the conversion. unless some special cases.

Answer (score -3):

Use **memcmp**. It is fastest and simple to use.
Direct memory compare is fastest way.
Use correct strategy to perform best approach. Try reading numbers in fixed buffer size and compare both. The numbers must be placed correctly in the buffer, right to left.

Comment: even comparing 10 charterers string would be faster than a integer comparison ?

Comment: The time of conversion to number increased costs.

Comment: Suppose that the converting time is equal to zero?

Comment: The `memcmp` won't work if the numbers are of different sizes.  For example, comparing a 4 digit number with a 3 digit number, the `memcmp` will compare the first digits, which is wrong (there should be an implied 0 as the first digit on the 3 digit number).

Comment: Even if all the strings were fixed-length (and stored back-to-back, not with an array of pointers) this would only have any hope of being as efficient as working with an array of integers if the strings were length 1, 2, or 4 (or 8 with 64bit code).  On x86 (and similar for all architectures), `cmp eax, [rsi]` does a 4-byte compare, but a 5-byte compare takes multiple instructions.